# Does the FAA restrict the color of pilot seat belts?

Tags: faa-regulations, general-aviation, seatbelts

In the US, is there a legal restriction to prevent the use of bright red pilot seat belts in GA aircraft?

Comment: What jurisdiction? What type of aircraft? I've not seen bright red color seat belts in the US GA aircraft I have been in.

Comment: For GA US registered aircrafts

Comment: The only red seat belts I remember seeing are in my Cherokee, but the rest of the interior is red, too.

Comment: My concern is possible visual interference with emergency buttons or levers that must be easily found, but I did not get any FAR reference that address this.

Comment: This company rewebs seat belts and has a whole bunch of colors, including red, so I’d so no. http://aircraftseatbelts.com/aircraft-seat-belt-colors/

Comment: This company also sells red belts. http://www.cmaviationservices.com/aircraft-seat-belts/

Comment: Is there a particular reason for this question? Did someone tell you there was such a regulation?

Answer (score 4):

No, there's no regulation on the color; the restraints just have to allow the crew to perform all their duties.

The [old 23.785 regulation](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=d54b82ffe2ee5265e70f214019d475e1&pitd=20150101&node=se14.1.23_1785&rgn=div8) said:

> (e) The restraint system for each crewmember must allow the crewmember, when seated with the safety belt and shoulder harness fastened, to perform all functions necessary for flight operations.

The [new 23.2535 regulation](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=d54b82ffe2ee5265e70f214019d475e1&mc=true&node=se14.1.23_12535&rgn=div8) says even less:

> Safety and survival equipment, required by the operating rules of this chapter, must be reliable, readily accessible, easily identifiable, and clearly marked to identify its method of operation.

And empirically, there are [many colors](http://aircraftseatbelts.com/aircraft-seat-belt-colors/) available. Googling will bring up plenty of images.